# Make one column of a grid to fill available formatting width

Tags: grid-layouts

Is it possible to make one ("Comment" in the example below) column to dynamically resize to fill available formatting width e.g. window?

I can't figure if it's possible with `ItemSize -> Scaled[...]` because I'd like to have the first two columns to be of their natural size (`ItemSize->Full`).

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap comments with [`Pane`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pane.html) and use the option `ImageSize -> Full`:

```
grid = {{"Name", "Value", "Comment"},
    {"name1", 123.2, ""},
    {"name2", 321.12332,  Pane["potentially very long commment ....................", 
     Alignment -> Center, ImageSize -> Full]}};

Grid[grid, Dividers -> All, Alignment -> {Center, Center}]
```

[image]

If we change the notebook's window width the width of the third column is adjusted:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need!